# How to prevent use of conflicting keywords in REST api calls in Express

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express

If I am creating a REST api with express for an application, as far as I'm aware, the order of the route definitions matter. For example, if I wrote my routes in the following order:

```
app.get('/users/:username', user.get);
app.get('/users/list', user.listAll);
```

then user.listAll could never be reached and the server would assign 'list' to the username parameter when a request was made to '/users/list'. So it's obvious that you want to reverse the order of the declaration of these routes. But here, we'll run into the same problem if a user creates an account with the username 'list', right?

So how do you prevent users from creating names with 'keywords' where keywords are defined here as strings that would conflict with the api routes.

I can think of two ways, but neither of them seem satisfying. First, you could keep a blacklist of strings that you compare against each username creation. But maintaining that would be a nightmare. And two, just pre-create those users in the database (as long as usernames are unique). That kind of seems a bit hacky but I can't think of many arguments against it.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I've faced this a while ago. You must be coming from a web background like me, because you are trying to use the 'slug' method to make user readable calls to the API. Using readable slugs is great and actually preferred in websites! There is actually not 1 way to do it in API's I've seen many ways that work, but I only know 1 way of making it scalable and descriptive in a way that works for almost every usecase.

**Always use ID's**

- One user: /users/:id
- List: /users/
- Friends: /users/:id/friends
- 1 friend of 1 user: /users/:id/friends/:id

Above is extendable and still descriptive! In addition I use versioning. (ex: /v1/users). This allows me to upgrade the API to a v2 while still supporting older clients :)

Now how do I lookup a specific user? **Use filters!**.. How?

/v1/users?username=:username

The above will **always** return a list of users. If username is unique this will still be a list, but only 1 record or just an empty list.

Use HTTP methods POST PUT GET DELETE

- POST on /users (201 created user)
- PUT/DELETE on /users (400 method not allowed) (optionally remove all??? Not recommended)
- PUT / DELETE on /users/:id (200 success)
- POST on /users/:id (400 user already exists)

Hope this will solve your case :)

Comment: I like this approach and I will use it. If I understand correctly, it seems like I should keep the nth path position reserved for either (a) a parameter or (b) a variety of predefined path strings. And in this case it's an exclusive-or. Since the strings are predefined I just have to make sure they don't conflict with each other, but I can have as many and as varied as I want in that nth position of the path.
And +1 for the versioning technique.

Comment: but what if you want to get all friends of all user?  `/users/friends/`
And... say admins also have friends (not to tell me to simply get `/friends/`)

Real case: /devices/infos/ and /queues/infos/  where you cant /infos/ ... ah ah